# how to get current cart items for different mobile app user with magento database?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, json, app

I want to get cart items in json formate for different mobile app user .
It works same as magento cart system **how can get ?** help me ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get cart item using quoteid

```
$quoteid = $_POST['quoteid'];    
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteid);
$items = $quote->getAllItems();
foreach($items as $item) 
{
    echo $item->getProductId();
    echo $item->getName();
}
```